# nodejs - mongodb native find all documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Following an example from the mongodb manual for nodejs, I am finding all documents from a db as follows

```
mongo.Db.connect(mongoUri, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } 
    else {
        db.collection('test').find().toArray(function(e, d) {
            console.log(d.length);
            db.close();
        });
    }
});
```

Now what I notice is that the entire set is converted to an array. As the dataset will grow, this will not be the ideal approach. Is there anyway to ***stream*** the data so it is not loaded in memory every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a `Cursor` ([reference](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html)):

```
var cursor = db.collection('test').find();

// Execute the each command, triggers for each document
cursor.each(function(err, item) {
    // If the item is null then the cursor is exhausted/empty and closed
    if(item == null) {
        db.close(); // you may not want to close the DB if you have more code....
        return;
    }
    // otherwise, do something with the item
});
```

If there's a lot of computation you need to do, you might consider whether a Map-Reduce ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)) would fit your needs as the code would execute on the DB server, rather than locally.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for map-reduce. I was trying to think about that but I am not sure I understand the principles of map-reduce on mongodb well enough to break down my problem.. But I will definitely revisit in the future.

Answer (score 19):

new & fast way when compare to loop approach

```
const data = await db.collection('parkingSigns').find().toArray();
data // array with all the documents in the collection.
```

Comment: will this approach remain fast with half a million records?

Comment: It works pretty fast for up to 50K records not sure about 500k but should be faster than loops.

Answer (score 14):

You can stream the results of a node.js native driver's query by calling [`stream()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#stream) on the returned cursor:

```
var stream = collection.find().stream();
stream.on('data', function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});
stream.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log('All done!');
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between stream() and next()

Answer (score 0):

Would limiting the query be an option? Literally with db.collection.find().limit()? The limit is parsed before sending the command to the server, so it only scans the amount of data in your limit.

Comment: My application actually requires to some mathematical computations on the data and return the most 'similar' documents. So I am returning all the documents and doing the computation locally. Now it would be nice if I can perform those computations on the database itself but I don't know if that is possible?