# What would be the fastest way select 1 million users from a collection in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
db.users.find({role:'seeker'}, {
    "email": 1,
    "name": 2
})
```

As suggested I ran

```
db.users.find({role:'seeker'}).explain()
```

to get this

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "users",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "role" : {
                "$eq" : "seeker"
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "role" : {
                    "$eq" : "seeker"
                }
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {

    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If I use the query above it takes  15-20 seconds to respond. I need to send email campaigns to bulk users every day. I have a node.js task to do this and while this task runs in background it slows down everything else even though node.js is not supposed to be blocking

Comment: Fetching a million docs from the collection is a lot of docs, even if indexed properly. Have you looked at streaming the results, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21630141/1259510)?

Comment: Streaming is interesting. I am thinking this use case exists for more than 10,000 companies toda, how are they doing it. e.g. let's say LinkedIn has to send a job alert email to everyone at 5pm. how many emails would linkedin have to fetch from DB then iterate over each email in the emails array, find matching jobs + prep email template and then send the email to a million times 100 users all over the world

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing it right. As simple as `select email, name from student where role='student'`

How many records do you have? Have you tuned/[profile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) your mongoDB instance anyhow?

Do you have index for `role` field?
`db.users.createIndex( { role: 1 } )` [create-an-index-to-support-read-operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/query-optimization/#create-an-index-to-support-read-operations)

You can use `explain` to get some insight if your query using index or not.

> For queries that cannot use an index, MongoDB must scan all documents
>   in a collection for documents that match the query.

If the list of emails is the same every time can you introduce a cache in your app?

Comment: **index role** It does make sense to create an index on role but often time we have to select the whole db regardless of the role

Comment: **explain:** I ran db.users.find(query).explain() and added the result to the question (cannot add readable code to comment).

Comment: **tuned/profile your mongoDB instance anyhow?** Nope, SQL background. never had to do it with SQL. How to start?

Comment: *Explain*: As I told you, you have no index for `role` field: 
explain.queryPlanner.indexFilterSet
A boolean that specifies whether MongoDB applied an index filter for the query shape. You have `"indexFilterSet" : false,`

You should add the index by doing `db.users.createIndex( { role: 1 } )`

*Profile*: Use the link I provided - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/

Comment: I have added the index using db.users.createIndex( { role: 1 } ). I also see the index is created but when i run explain I still see `"indexFilterSet" : false`

Comment: Can you post:
`db.users.find({role:'seeker'}).explain("executionStats")`

Comment: also what is the version of your mongo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128648/discussion-between-vadim-kirilchuk-and-puretext).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after adding the index the explain looks correct and indeed using the index:

```
{ 
"queryPlanner" : { 
"plannerVersion" : 1, 
"namespace" : "users", 
"indexFilterSet" : false, 
"parsedQuery" : { 
"role" : { 
"$eq" : "seeker" 
} 
}, 
"winningPlan" : { 
"stage" : "FETCH", 
"inputStage" : { 
"stage" : "IXSCAN", 
"keyPattern" : { 
"role" : 1 
}, 
"indexName" : "role_1", 
"isMultiKey" : false, 
"direction" : "forward", 
"indexBounds" : { 
"role" : [ 
"[\"seeker\", \"seeker\"]" 
] 
} 
} 
}, 
"rejectedPlans" : [ ] 
}, 
"executionStats" : { 
"executionSuccess" : true, 
"nReturned" : 850834, 
"executionTimeMillis" : 13217, 
"totalKeysExamined" : 850834, 
"totalDocsExamined" : 850834, 
"executionStages" : { 
"stage" : "FETCH", 
"nReturned" : 850834, 
"executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1970, 
"works" : 941141, 
"advanced" : 850834, 
"needTime" : 0, 
"needFetch" : 90306, 
"saveState" : 93946, 
"restoreState" : 93946, 
"isEOF" : 1, 
"invalidates" : 0, 
"docsExamined" : 850834, 
"alreadyHasObj" : 0, 
"inputStage" : { 
"stage" : "IXSCAN", 
"nReturned" : 850834, 
"executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 560, 
"works" : 850834, 
"advanced" : 850834, 
"needTime" : 0, 
"needFetch" : 0, 
"saveState" : 93946, 
"restoreState" : 93946, 
"isEOF" : 1, 
"invalidates" : 0, 
"keyPattern" : { 
"role" : 1 
}, 
"indexName" : "role_1", 
"isMultiKey" : false, 
"direction" : "forward", 
"indexBounds" : { 
"role" : [ 
"[\"seeker\", \"seeker\"]" 
] 
}, 
"keysExamined" : 850834, 
"dupsTested" : 0, 
"dupsDropped" : 0, 
"seenInvalidated" : 0, 
"matchTested" : 0 
} 
} 
}, 
"serverInfo" : { 
"host" : "xxx", 
"port" : 12345, 
"version" : "3.0.12", 
"gitVersion" : "33934938e0e95d534cebbaff656cde916b9c3573" 
}, 
"ok" : 1 
}
```

I think that's the fastest thing you can get by doing "retrieve all at once".
I wonder if you can [retrieve only specific fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/), like 'name' and 'email' only:

> If you specify no projection, the find() method returns all fields of
>   all documents that match the query.
>
> db.inventory.find( { type: 'food' } ) This operation will return all
>   documents in the inventory collection where the value of the type
>   field is 'food'. The returned documents contain all fields.

So, if you don't want mongo to return all the fields for each student, just pass some additional parameters, like this:

```
db.users.find( { role: 'student' }, { name: 1, email: 1, _id:0 } )
```

Obviously reading all the fields from your hard drive is a time consuming operation, so retrieving only 2 fields from 10 will give your query significant boost. In terms of sql it is a difference between: `select * from T` and `select name from T`.

I wonder have you considered using pagination and batching get/send, i.e. retrieve first 10000 of students, send them emails then retrieve next 10000 students, send them email, repeat..?

You can also try to do a horizontal scaling by sharding users across your mongo db instances but it depends on your hardware capabilities and I don't think if you have only one server it will give you any benefits. So, the paging should be a way to go.

Comment: Thank you for copying back the explain's results hire and your time and effort in finding a solution. About creating index and select two fields I've tried it and there is not much difference. When I started learning SQL10 years ago, that's what I ready in pretty much every book. Have an index and select the fields you need for faster queries .. But in reality sites like linkedin / facebook are sending more than 1 million personalized emails a day.

Comment: If selecting the emails is taking their cronjob more than 15 seconds and each email template needs to be personalized. That cron task is gonna hog the mem like shite.

Comment: Also I tried pagination in cron task and learned that I cannot trust keeping a track of the fact that emails were sent to user 1, user 2, user 3, and its needs to be sent to user 4, user 5, user 6 because the task couldn't mark the email sent on user 5 and kept sending him emails all day.. So that approach has a risky, a very risk point of failure that costed me a subscriber

Comment: but again thank you for your time and effort for your earnest endeavor to solve this

Comment: @PureText If we speak about linkedin/facebook I bet they are not using one server to do that. They spread amount of work between several instances. That's the key, horizontal scaling. I think you should read about sharding/replication if you face a limit of one server.

Comment: Thank you, will look into it.